# Customized Convert Numbers to Words with PHP

Tags: php

I have this php code which converts numbers to words:

```
<?php
class NumericHelper {
        public static function ToWord($number) {
            $digit1 = array (
                    0 => 'zero',
                    1 => 'one',
                    2 => 'two',
                    3 => 'three',
                    4 => 'four',
                    5 => 'five',
                    6 => 'six',
                    7 => 'seven',
                    8 => 'eight',
                    9 => 'nine'
            );
            $digit1_5 = array (
                    1 => 'eleven',
                    2 => 'twelve',
                    3 => 'thirteen',
                    4 => 'fourteen',
                    5 => 'fifteen',
                    6 => 'sixteen',
                    7 => 'seventeen',
                    8 => 'eighteen',
                    9 => 'nineteen'
            );
            $digit2 = array (
                    1 => 'ten',
                    2 => 'twenty',
                    3 => 'thirty',
                    4 => 'forty',
                    5 => 'fifty',
                    6 => 'sixty',
                    7 => 'seventy',
                    8 => 'eighty',
                    9 => 'ninety'
            );
            $digit3 = array (
                    1 => 'one hundred',
                    2 => 'two hundred',
                    3 => 'three hundred',
                    4 => 'four hundred',
                    5 => 'five hundred',
                    6 => 'six hundred',
                    7 => 'seven hundred',
                    8 => 'eight hundred',
                    9 => 'nine hundred'
            );
            $steps = array (
                    1 => 'thousand',
                    2 => 'million',
                    3 => 'billion',
                    4 => 'trillion',
                    5 => 'quadrillion',
                    6 => 'quintillion',
                    7 => 'sextillion',
                    8 => 'septillion',
                    9 => 'octillion',
                    10 => 'nonillion',
                    11 => 'decillion'
            );
            $t = array (
                    'and' => 'and'
            );

            return self::toWord2 ( $number, $digit1, $digit1_5, $digit2, $digit3, $t );
        }
        private function toWord2($number, array $digit1, array $digit1_5, array $digit2, array $digit3, array $t) {
            $formated = self::numberFormat ( $number, 0, '.', ',' );
            $groups = explode ( ',', $formated );

            $steps = count ( $groups );

            $parts = array ();
            foreach ( $groups as $step => $group ) {
                $group_words = self::groupToWords ( $group, $digit1, $digit1_5, $digit2, $digit3 );
                if ($group_words) {
                    $part = implode ( ' ' . $t ['and'] . ' ', $group_words );
                    if (isset ( $steps [$steps - $step - 1] )) {
                        $part .= ' ' . $steps [$steps - $step - 1];
                    }
                    $parts [] = $part;
                }
            }
            return implode ( ' ' . $t ['and'] . ' ', $parts );
        }
        private static function numberFormat($number, $decimal_precision = 0, $decimals_separator = '.', $thousands_separator = ',') {
            $number = explode ( '.', str_replace ( ' ', '', $number ) );
            $number [0] = str_split ( strrev ( $number [0] ), 3 );
            $total_segments = count ( $number [0] );
            for($i = 0; $i < $total_segments; $i ++) {
                $number [0] [$i] = strrev ( $number [0] [$i] );
            }
            $number [0] = implode ( $thousands_separator, array_reverse ( $number [0] ) );
            if (! empty ( $number [1] )) {
                $number [1] = Round ( $number [1], $decimal_precision );
            }
            return implode ( $decimals_separator, $number );
        }
        private static function groupToWords($group, array $digit1, array $digit1_5, array $digit2, array $digit3) {
            $d3 = floor ( $group / 100 );
            $d2 = floor ( ($group - $d3 * 100) / 10 );
            $d1 = $group - $d3 * 100 - $d2 * 10;

            $group_array = array ();

            if ($d3 != 0) {
                $group_array [] = $digit3 [$d3];
            }

            if ($d2 == 1 && $d1 != 0) { // 11-19
                $group_array [] = $digit1_5 [$d1];
            } else if ($d2 != 0 && $d1 == 0) { // 10-20-...-90
                $group_array [] = $digit2 [$d2];
            } else if ($d2 == 0 && $d1 == 0) { // 00
            } else if ($d2 == 0 && $d1 != 0) { // 1-9
                $group_array [] = $digit1 [$d1];
            } else { // Others
                $group_array [] = $digit2 [$d2];
                $group_array [] = $digit1 [$d1];
            }

            if (! count ( $group_array )) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return $group_array;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

it works like this: echos 54,687,634 as: fifty and four and six hundred and eighty and seven and six hundred and thirty and four

but I want to show like this: `fifty X four million and six hundred X eighty X seven thousand and six hundred X thirty X four`

Comment: Hint, use the modulus operator.

Comment: @TecBrat i'm new in php. can you explain it by details?

Comment: look at this. http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Comment: @TecBrat i couldn't solve it. can you guide me more

Comment: Looks like Augwa gave you the complete solution. When you're looking at it, notice the percent sign. `%` that's the modulus operator. It returns the remainder of a division problem and is used in a case like this to determine how many of a given unit are in the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert_number_to_words($number) {

$hyphen      = '-';
$conjunction = ' and ';
$separator   = ', ';
$negative    = 'negative ';
$decimal     = ' point ';
$dictionary  = array(
    0                   => 'zero',
    1                   => 'one',
    2                   => 'two',
    3                   => 'three',
    4                   => 'four',
    5                   => 'five',
    6                   => 'six',
    7                   => 'seven',
    8                   => 'eight',
    9                   => 'nine',
    10                  => 'ten',
    11                  => 'eleven',
    12                  => 'twelve',
    13                  => 'thirteen',
    14                  => 'fourteen',
    15                  => 'fifteen',
    16                  => 'sixteen',
    17                  => 'seventeen',
    18                  => 'eighteen',
    19                  => 'nineteen',
    20                  => 'twenty',
    30                  => 'thirty',
    40                  => 'fourty',
    50                  => 'fifty',
    60                  => 'sixty',
    70                  => 'seventy',
    80                  => 'eighty',
    90                  => 'ninety',
    100                 => 'hundred',
    1000                => 'thousand',
    1000000             => 'million',
    1000000000          => 'billion',
    1000000000000       => 'trillion',
    1000000000000000    => 'quadrillion',
    1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
);

if (!is_numeric($number)) {
    return false;
}

if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
    // overflow
    trigger_error(
        'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
    return false;
}

if ($number < 0) {
    return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
}

$string = $fraction = null;

if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
    list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
}

switch (true) {
    case $number < 21:
        $string = $dictionary[$number];
        break;
    case $number < 100:
        $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
        $units  = $number % 10;
        $string = $dictionary[$tens];
        if ($units) {
            $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
        }
        break;
    case $number < 1000:
        $hundreds  = $number / 100;
        $remainder = $number % 100;
        $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
    default:
        $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
        $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
        $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
        $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
            $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
}

if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
    $string .= $decimal;
    $words = array();
    foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
        $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
    }
    $string .= implode(' ', $words);
}
return $string;}
```

Comment: code was not inserted properly previously , so please do check this and let me know whether it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
    $hyphen      = '-';
    $conjunction = ' and ';
    $separator   = ', ';
    $negative    = 'negative ';
    $decimal     = ' point ';
    $dictionary  = array(
        0                   => 'zero',
        1                   => 'one',
        2                   => 'two',
        3                   => 'three',
        4                   => 'four',
        5                   => 'five',
        6                   => 'six',
        7                   => 'seven',
        8                   => 'eight',
        9                   => 'nine',
        10                  => 'ten',
        11                  => 'eleven',
        12                  => 'twelve',
        13                  => 'thirteen',
        14                  => 'fourteen',
        15                  => 'fifteen',
        16                  => 'sixteen',
        17                  => 'seventeen',
        18                  => 'eighteen',
        19                  => 'nineteen',
        20                  => 'twenty',
        30                  => 'thirty',
        40                  => 'fourty',
        50                  => 'fifty',
        60                  => 'sixty',
        70                  => 'seventy',
        80                  => 'eighty',
        90                  => 'ninety',
        100                 => 'hundred',
        1000                => 'thousand',
        1000000             => 'million',
        1000000000          => 'billion',
        1000000000000       => 'trillion',
        1000000000000000    => 'quadrillion',
        1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units  = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds  = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}?>`
```

Use the code above, and let me know your views.
Cheers :)